# Entendimento sobre delimitador de string

Tags: c, string

```
char *strdelc(char *s, char ch)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=j=0; s[i]!='\0';i++)
        if(s[i]!=ch)
            s[j++]=s[i];
    s[j]='\0';    
    return s;    
}
```

Essa função tem como intuito apagar o caractere enviado pelo usuário, mas não consigo entender duas coisas.

Como o `j++` adicionará algo a `s[0]`, já que ele é incrementado?

E como o `s[j] = '\0'` não vai substituir alguma letra, pois quando o for se encerra não tem nada para incrementar o `j`?

Comment: `j++` é pós-incremento, primeiro utiliza o valor corrente de `j` na expressão e por último incrementa.

Comment: Quanto ao '\0' final a variável `j` já foi incrementada e já indica a posição seguinte ao último caractere do array que interessa e apenas sinalizará o final da string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Farei comentários mostrando o que faz cada parte, estou reescrevendo partes para ficar mais legível e quebrando algumas para facilitar os comentários:

```
char *strdelc(char *s, char ch) {
    int j = 0; //faz a declaração a atribuição junto para ficar claro que a operação está completa
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) { //já declarei a variável onde vai usar, é um for clássico
        if (s[i] != ch) { //só entra em certas condições
            s[j++] = s[i]; //aqui há um ordem de precedência do que deve executar, veja abaixo
        }
    }
    s[j] = '\0'; // aqui pega a próxima posição, é a mesma explicação porque funciona o incremento
    return s;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/DelChar.c).

`j` é usado fora do laço e precisa declarar fora, mas `i` só usa dentro do laço então é melhor só existir ali dentro.

O operador `++`é um incremento que ocorre depois de utilizar o valor da variável. De fato em primeiro momento ele parece confuso porque porque `j += 1` ele faz um pré-incremento de 1 então intuitivamente as pessoas que o `j++` também faz, mas o pré-incremento é feito assim `++j`. Nesse caso `j` será incrementado e depois o valor obtido é usado em alguma operação.

No pós-incremento a operação de incrementar é deixada por último, para o compilador esse código é o mesmo que escrever isto:

```
char *strdelc(char *s, char ch) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (s[i] != ch) {
            s[j] = s[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    s[j] = '\0';
    return s;
}
```

Quando a variável sendo incrementada em um um *statement*, ou seja, uma linha separada, onde só o incremento acontece não importa se está usando o operador de pré ou pós-incremento, acontecerá igual porque ele não tem outros efeitos. Mas quando essa operação estão dentro de uma outra expressão faz toda diferença porque o valor que será usado para completar a expressão está sem o incremento quando usa o pós.

Olhando esse segundo código dá para entender mais facilmente que a última execução que manipula o `j` já está na próxima posição porque a última coisa que aconteceu foi o incremento. Ou seja, ele usou em `s[j++]` o valor atual de `j`, mas logo depois ele foi pra próxima posição, então quando for colocar o terminador será colocado na próxima posição.

`j` sempre fica engatilhado para a próxima posição, e como começa no 0 a próxima antes de entrar no laço já é a primeira letra.

Acho que entende que `j` controla a posição real de onde o novo conteúdo está andando. E acho que entende que no momento que termina deve colocar o terminador logo em seguida para que indique que o texto termina ali e outros algoritmos não lerem além daquele ponto porque apesar de ter uma memória alocada e dados ali eles não fazem parte mais do texto correto.

Em situações simples assim esse operador não é problemático, em outras mais complexas é, inclusive se usasse outra vez o `j` na mesma linha (*statement*) já poderia ter problemas, então a recomendação seria não usar assim para deixar claro para o compilador qual é sua real intenção.